# Splitting and creating 2 rows out of one in R data table

Tags: r, datatable

I have a dataset (dt) like this in R:

```
n       id      val
1       1&&2    10
2       3       20
3       4&&5    30
```

And what I want to get is

```
n       id      val
1       1       10
2       2       10
3       3       20
4       4       30
5       5       30
```

I know that to split ids I need to do something like this:
`id_split <- strsplit(dt$id,"&&")`

But how do I create new rows with the same `val` for ids which were initially together in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may `cbind` the splits to get a column which you `cbind` again to the `val` (recycling).

```
res <- do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, id=lapply(strsplit(dat$id, "&&"), cbind), 
                          val=dat$val))
res <- cbind(n=1:nrow(res), res)
res
#   n id val
# 1 1  1  10
# 2 2  2  10
# 3 3  3  20
# 4 4  4  30
# 5 5  5  30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lengths` from the split of `id` and expand your rows. Then set `n` to be the sequece of the length of your data frame, i.e.

```
l1 <- strsplit(as.character(df$id), '&&')
res_df <- transform(df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(l1)),], 
                    id = unlist(l1), 
                    n = seq_along(unlist(l1)))
```

which gives,

> ```
>     n id val
> 1   1  1  10
> 1.1 2  2  10
> 2   3  3  20
> 3   4  4  30
> 3.1 5  5  30
> ```

You can remove the rownames with `rownames(res_df) <- NULL`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looking for tidy solution,

```
dt %>%
  separate(id, into = paste0("id", 1:2),sep = "&&") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(id1,id2), names_to = "id_name", values_to = "id") %>% 
  drop_na(id) %>% 
  select(n, id, val)
```

output as

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      n id      val
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 1        10
2     1 2        10
3     2 3        20
4     3 4        30
5     3 5        30
```

**Edit:**
As suggested by @sotos, and completely missed by me. one liner solution

```
d %>% separate_rows(id, ,sep = "&&")
```

gives same output as

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      n id      val
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 1        10
2     1 2        10
3     2 3        20
4     3 4        30
5     3 5        30
```

Comment: you can also do `dt %>% separate_rows(id, sep = '&&')`

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution.

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- fread('n       id      val
1       1&&2    10
2       3       20
3       4&&5    30')


DT[,.(id=unlist(strsplit(id,split ="&&"))),by=.(n,val)][,n:=.I][]
#>    n val id
#> 1: 1  10  1
#> 2: 2  10  2
#> 3: 3  20  3
#> 4: 4  30  4
#> 5: 5  30  5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Note:**

A more rebosut solution is `by = 1:nrow(DT)`. But you need to play around your other columns though.

Answer (score 1):

`tstrplit` by `id` from `data.table` can do the job

```r
library(data.table)
df <- setDT(df)[,.('id' = tstrsplit(id, "&&")), by = c('n','val')]
df[,'n' := seq(.N)]

df
   n val id
1: 1  10  1
2: 2  10  2
3: 3  20  3
4: 4  30  4
5: 5  30  5
```